# T-sql using values from one table and displaying them in different columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

My database Table looks like:

```
ID | INDEX | Value |
1  |   0   |   3   |
1  |   1   |   5   |
1  |   2   |   7   |
2  |   0   |   4   |
2  |   1   |   6   |
2  |   2   |   2   |
```

What I want my output to look like is the difference of the values column based on their index
i.e. value(id=2,index = i) - value(id = 1, index = i) so the output table will look like

```
INDEX | Delta Value |
  0   |     1       |
  1   |     1       |
  2   |    -5       |
```

My attempt at solving this problem is as follows:

```
SELECT Top 6
    col1.value column1,
    col2.value column2,
    col2.value - col1.value
FROM My_Table col1
INNER JOIN  My_Table col2
    ON col1.index = col2.index 
WHERE col1.id = 1 
    OR col2.id = 2
```

I know there are problems with this query. But I just haven't been able to produce the output that I want. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you're using t-sql, you are **not** using MySql. Watch your tags.

Comment: Sorry, I'll take care of that in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by join

```
select
    t1.ind, t1.value - t2.value as delta
from My_Table as t1
    inner join My_Table as t2 on t2.id = 2 and t2.ind = t1.ind
where t1.id = 1
```

Or by simple aggregate:

```
select
    ind, sum(case id when 1 then 1 when 2 then -1 end * value) as delta
from My_Table
group by ind
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something like this?

```
select
    col1.value column1,
    col2.value column2,
    col2.value - col1.value AS delta
From My_Table col1
INNER JOIN  My_Table col2 
    ON col1.index = col2.index
    AND col2.id = 2 
where col1.id = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

have a look at mine

```
 select t1.[index],
    t2.value-t1.value
 from my_table t1 inner join my_table t2
 on t1.[index] = t2.[index]
 where t1.id = 1 and t2.id = 2
 order by t1.[index]
```